# JS advantages of module pattern?

Tags: javascript

I know it's a duplicate but I don't understand the other posts: I'm doing an exercise on freeCodeCamp that I don't understand, it's about modules: What's the advantage of doing this:

```
const motionModule = (function() {
  return {
    isCuteMixin: function(obj) {
      obj.isCute = function() {
        return true;
      };
    },
    singMixin: function(obj) {
      obj.sing = function() {
        console.log("Singing to an awesome tune");
      };
    }
  };
})();
```

instead of this:

```
const motionModule = {
  isCuteMixin: function(obj) {
    obj.isCute = function() {
      return true;
    };
  },
  singMixin: function(obj) {
    obj.sing = function() {
      console.log("Singing to an awesome tune");
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: I see no difference between the two in your examples; the "advantages" would be if you had some top-level `function` code, that would have been hidden

Comment: Look again, there is a difference.

Comment: @FUZIION not in the example provided. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes but you have to see it from a "teachers" perspective. There's no output difference but the first one has an extra advantage, see the answer by @YK1

Comment: @FUZIION point being that "there is a difference" is not useful information by itself. You may as well have not commented that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One advantage is you can emulate private variables and methods which are not accessible from outside the returned object. This helps keeping the data and functionality together and avoids corruption of global namespace.

```
const motionModule = (function() {
  let song = 'My song'; // private variable

  function singTheSong() {
     // private method
  }

  return {
    isCuteMixin: function(obj) {
      obj.isCute = function() {
        return true;
      };
    },
    singMixin: function(obj) {
      obj.sing = function() {
        console.log("Singing to an awesome tune" + song);
        singTheSong();
      };
    }
  };
})();

// cannot call singTheSong from here
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a module, you would often want the methods to be able to access each other and shared variables. To do this in your 2nd example, you need to attach them to the object and access them via the `this` keyword, and also (within the mixin creating functions) use arrow functions to ensure `this` refers to the right object.

```js
const motionModule = {
  song: "La La La",
  sing: function() {
    console.log(this.song);
  },
  singMixin: function(obj) {
    obj.sing = () => {
      console.log(`Singing ${this.song}`);
    };
  }
};
const a = {};
motionModule.sing();
motionModule.singMixin(a);
a.sing();
```

Modern ES6 `class` declarations also require you to work in this way.

```js
class MotionModule {
  song = "La La La";
  sing() {
    console.log(this.song);
  }
  singMixin(obj) {
    obj.sing = () => {
      console.log(`Singing ${this.song}`);
    };
  }
}
const motionModule = new MotionModule();
motionModule.sing();
const a = {};
motionModule.singMixin(a);
a.sing();
```

As shown in another answer, the first example (an immediately invoked function expression) allows you to access other variables and methods defined within the module without using `this`, and gives you greater control over which methods and variables are accessible from outside the module.